# Create ASP.Net Core 3.1 Identity User and Roles Administration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.Net Core 3.1 app correctly using the Identity functionality. All the tutorials and docs that I look at seem to assume that the User and Role and Claims management functionality is readily available. I found the scaffolding for the basic authentication like the login, register, logout, and account pages.

I haven't been able to find any clear documentation on if those Admin functions are scaffolded out, installable, or if I just have to create them from scratch. I can do that, I was just hoping for some pre-packaged functionality. Are the administrative functions (CRUD User, CRUD Roles, CRUD Claims) available as scaffolded pages, or do I have to build them all myself?

Comment: AFAIK, you could scaffold the CRUD operations for the database models , which includes controllers and views.refer to https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/build-crud-application-with-asp-net-core-entity-framework-visual-studio-2019.aspx

Comment: Hey NickNuke I am also searching for .netCore 3.1 fw,
Do you found any useful pointer for the same?
I am also struggling/revising for Role configuration in Startup.cs.
Hi @XueliChen, I doubt your link is not related to the thread's question.

Comment: I did find some information. 1) I started by creating my own XXUser class and XXUserStore based on User.cs and UserStore.cs. 2) I found that things weren't working because you have to NOT include the line ".AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)". If you include that line, things just don't work. 3) The claims weren't coming through, and it turned out that I needed to create my own ProfileService. I got some help from this page: https://deblokt.com/2019/09/27/05-identityserver4-adding-custom-properties-to-user/